# adobe javascript print from the second page to the end

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe

```
this.print false,1,8,true
```

will print the 2nd page to page 9, how can I print from 2nd to end?
I read adobe javascript reference and find this

> If only nStart is specified, the range of pages is the single page
>   specified by nStart.

is that a work around to print from 2nd page to the end?

Answer (score 0):

I soved this myself by get the page count

```
x = PDDoc.GetNumPages
jso.print false, 1, x-1, true
```